# couchdb request never completes

Tags: azure, couchdb

I am trying to request a large number of documents from my database (which has over 400k documents).  I started using _all_docs built-in view.  I first tried with this query:

```
http://database:port/databasename/_all_docs?limit=100&include_docs=true
```

No problem. Completes as expected.  Now to ramp it up:

```
http://database:port/databasename/_all_docs?limit=1000&include_docs=true
```

Still fine.  Took longer, more data, etc. as expected.  Ramp it up again:

```
http://database:port/databasename/_all_docs?limit=10000&include_docs=true
```

Request never completes.  The Dev tools in chrome show Size = 5.3MB (seems to be significant), and this occurs no matter what value for the limit parameter I use that is over 6500ish.  No matter if i specify 6500 or 10,000, it always returns 5.3MB downloaded, and the request stalls.

I have also tried other combinations, such as "skip" and it seems that limit + skip must be < 6500 or I get the same stall.

My environment: Couchdb 1.6.1, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, Azure A1 standard

Comment: what tool are you using for this http call ?   is it curl or just the browser

Comment: @BrijRajSingh - this was using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

you have to prewarm your queries, just throwing a 100K or more docs and expecting that you'd get them out of couchdb won't work, it just won't work.

When you ask for some items from a view (in your case Default View), at the first read CouchDB will notice that the B-tree for the view doesn't exist yet, so it goes ahead and builds it on the first read. Depending on how many documents you have in your database, that can take a while, putting a good work load on your database.

On every subsequent read, CouchDB will check if documents have changed since the last write, and throw the changed documents at the map and reduce function. So if you only query some views from time to time, but have lots of changes in between, expect some delays on the next read.

There are 2 ways to handle this situation
1. Pre-warm your view - run a cronjob that does reads to make sure that your view has the B-Tree for this View.
2. Prepare your view in advance for a particular query before inserting the data in the couchdb.

and for now if you really want to read all your docs, don't read them all at once, rather use the skip, limit range queries.

Comment: I think I understand and agree with your general premise, however is 6500 documents too much?  Should I not expect the query to respond, event if it takes along time?  Perhaps just in writing this response, I think I will check the HTTP timeout value on the CouchDb server - perhaps its timing out, but not closing the connection.

Comment: Which could be the case, but do you actually have a need to return such big datasets in one go? 6500 is not too much but it also depends on the config of your couchdb server, and the size of your documents